# mod_rewrite and titles with '.php' extension

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a database that has a url colomn like `this-is-the-title.php`
I want to active mod_rewrite here with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?url=$1
```

But I have problem with `.php` extension. This rule works only with `this-is-the-title` not `this-is-the-title.php` . Is there any way to active mod rewrite with titles that have .php extension or I have to change titles?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rewriterule doesn't allow the dot character... If you want `something.php` to match, use this:

`^([a-zA-Z0-9-/.]+)$`

I've also simplified the fact there could be a trailing slash: since the slash is already allowed, a trailing slash will match as well.

Don't forget to add some rewriteconds to avoid rewriting existing directories or files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Btw, Adding a php extension to rewritten URLs doesn't make any sense and you should stick to clean URLs with no extension at all.

So you end up with somehting like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-/.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ news.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: into square parentesys there is not need to excape .)

Comment: This is the best answer I ever seen because it does not only gives you an answer but also gives you ideas to prevent hacks

Comment: I never intended to explain how to prevent "hacks" with this answer. Testing the file exists would actually have the opposite effect as it would NOT rewrite and deliver the file (which is what you want most of the time, otherwise you would not be able to load static files like your stylesheets or javascript). Even if you wanted to prevent some file from being directly accessed, rewrite rules are NOT the way to do it (move them outside of your public space altogether or use ACLs)

Answer (score 0):

maybe using a rule similar to

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)\.php$ news.php?url=$1 [L]
```

?

Comment: I was thinking he needs just a rule to match the url to rewrite, not the entire set.

Comment: Some education doesn't hurt ;-)